# Eclipse running out of memory when starting Minecraft client

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, minecraft-forge

I have been following a mod tutorial and have finally gotten to the point where we are supposed to launch a Minecraft instance inside of Eclipse to test the mod. Whenever I try to do that I keep getting this error:
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`
(Full Error log: https://pastebin.com/t7AbTguS). I have tried giving Eclipse more memory but that doesn't seem to work. I have tried everything I have seen online but nothing works. I am on OSX with 8GB of RAM. Here's my eclipse.ini: https://pastebin.com/Ybi2jsx8.

Comment: The current eclipse.ini only allows 2G, how much more have you tried?

Comment: I have tried everything up to 2G

Comment: You should try at least up to 4G.

Comment: I just changed the -Xmx2G to -Xmx4G then quit eclipse and restarted it and it still crashes.

Comment: Maybe some texture gets loaded multiple times? At least according to the stacktrace minecraft fails while loading an image. Might be a hint that the heap gets filled up with images. In either way, the error is not reproduce-able. Any answer to this question wont be much more than a random guess

Comment: @Paul Any idea where I should post this question or what I should do?

Comment: @HittmanA Since its a memory-issue you should start [searching for memory leaks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks001.html) and double check your resource allocation (textures, images, json, etc.) for anything that might get loaded repeatedly. Unfortunately Im not coding any mods myself, but Im pretty sure there are communities out there dedicated to coding minecraft mods, which could help you further with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory settings in the eclipse.ini control how much memory Eclipse itself uses. They do **not** control the memory used when you launch another program (such as minecraft) from within Eclipse.

To change the settings for a launched program open the 'Run > Run Configurations' dialog.

Find the entry for your program in the tree on the left.

Put your settings in the 'VM arguments' section on the 'Arguments' tab.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks so much!